# Is there a way to issue a DisableSecureEventInput command in Terminal on a Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have 2 apps that issue an EnableSecureEventInput when they are launched, but they do not issue a DisableSecureEventInput when quit, this stops me from using some shortcut apps like Typinator.

I realise that I could just re-boot my Mac, but that's pretty inconvenient every time I use one of these apps, so I would like to know how to do this via terminal if it is possible.

I have searched everywhere that I can think of, but have just drawn a complete blank so far, and I've contacted the developer about the issue, but I'm not too hopeful for a response.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

MacOS Catalina version 10.15.7

Answer (score 0):

I've since found out that this isn't possible. DisableSecureEventInput has to be issued by the app that issued the EnableSecureEventInput. This is a security requirement, and thinking about it now, that makes sense.